# C++ : Why isn't my call to "std::uninitialized_copy" working?

Tags: c++, allocator, initialization

I building a simple class that is supposed to mimic the functionality of the std::string class (as an exercise!):

```
#ifndef _STR12_1_H
#define _STR12_1_H

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Str12_1
{
public:

    typedef char* iterator;
    typedef const char* const_iterator;
    typedef long size_type;


    Str12_1();
    Str12_1(const Str12_1& str);
    Str12_1(const char *p);
    Str12_1(const std::string& s);

    size_type size() const;

    //Other member functions


private:
    iterator first;
    iterator onePastLast;
    iterator onePastAllocated;
};
```

In order to avoid the overhead associated with "new" (and to increase my familiarity with the `<memory>` header), i've opted to use the library's allocator template class to allocate memory for my string. Here is an example of my use of it in the copy constructor:

```
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>

using std::allocator;
using std::raw_storage_iterator;
using std::uninitialized_copy;


Str12_1::Str12_1(const Str12_1& str)
{
    allocator<char> charAlloc;
    first = charAlloc.allocate(str.size());
    onePastLast = onePastAllocated = first + str.size();
    *onePastLast = '\0';

    raw_storage_iterator<char*, char> it(first);

    uninitialized_copy(str.first, str.onePastLast, it);


}
```

The compiler keeps telling me two errors on the "uninitialized_copy" line which both lead back to headers in the library, :

```
error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'char*'

error: no match for 'operator!=' in '__first != __last'
```

The problem is that I don't understand where on that line the conversion from char to char* is, and why two pointers of the same type (str.first, str.onePastLast) cannot be compared with "!=".

I could use "new", but as stated before, I want to get practice with `<memory>`. So can someone tell me why this isn't working?

Comment: The default allocator just calls `new` under the hood. There's no magic in it. It's there to allow the user to customize the memory allocation strategy, by supplying a different allocator. But the default one just does the same thing as `new`. Just thought you might want to know that, even if it doesn't answer your question :)

Comment: Are you sure? What I gathered from Accelerated C++ and every other resource online is that "new" calls the type's default constructor after it allocates space, while ".allocate" does not.

Comment: [Clearly the problem is your bad include guard identifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier). :)

Comment: @Kevin: Yes, but for a primitive `char`, `new char[x];` does nothing, and only `new char[x]()` zeroes out the block. - As to copying the string, `strcpy` and the like are probably better, since `uninitialized_copy` has a rather specific task (invoke the constructor to copy complicated types into uninitialized memory) which is not necessary for a primitive type.

Comment: @GMan: Ha! Yes... that's generated by NetBeans automatically whenever  I create a new header file, and I was just too lazy to change it! I knew someone would mention it though.

Comment: @UncleBens: Ah! Understood. I would still like to understand why exactly my call isn't working. Have any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the standard `raw_storage_iterator` does not typedef `value_type` to be `T`, but it's `void` instead:

```
template <class OutputIterator, class T>
class raw_storage_iterator
: public iterator<output_iterator_tag,void,void,void,void>
                                      ^^^^
```

whereas `uninitialized_copy` has to use that typedef:

```
template <class InputIterator, class ForwardIterator>
ForwardIterator uninitialized_copy(InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
ForwardIterator result);
```

Effects:

```
for (; first != last; ++result, ++first)
::new (static_cast<void*>(&*result))
typename iterator_traits<ForwardIterator>::value_type(*first);
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

In your code, after all substitutions, this leads to:

```
new (...&*result) void (*first);
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                 invalid use here
```

From that you can conclude that those two were never meant to work together.

If you want to use `raw_storage_iterator`, then it should be fine to pass it to `std::copy` since all the magic happens in the `operator=(const T&)` overload.

If you think any of this is necessary for a primitive like `char` where you might just allocate with `new char[x]` (NB! terminating NUL) and copy with `strcpy`.

Comment: Ah! This is exactly what i'm looking for. Thanks. (What's weird is that it does not compile in GCC, but does with MS's Visual C++ compiler.

Comment: With VC++ it doesn't compile for me for the second error you get, and it pretty much tells me that `uninitialized_copy` is "deprecated" anyway.